# Copy 16 bits hash on 32 bits array

Tags: c, hash, printf, strcat

I have a problem with my use of `sprintf` and `strcat`. Here's my code :

```
unsigned char hashResults[8][16];
unsigned char tmp[2];
unsigned char hash[8][32];

transformation("toto", 4, hashResults);

for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(tmp,"%2.2x",hashResults[k][i]);
        strcat(hash[k],tmp);
    }
    printf("%d \n%s\n", strlen(hash[k]), hash[k]);
}
printf("Test : %s\n", hash[3]);
```

The function `transformation()` gives me 8 hashes on 16 bits.

I use `sprintf` and `strcat` to get hash on 32 bits. When I try to read all `hash[k]`, `strlen(hash[8])` returns to me 32 (it's correct), and the string is correct too. 
But, when I try to read `hash[3]` outside the loop it contains all values after it.

For example, the output of my program :

```
32 - 4a18e332afba75b9734e875323f452f8

32 - b96833277faf31a5915c769f44634506

32 - f89f6dd8cd5aee79de3b2c0c27cafe2e

32 - c9f629472c862c1e7542f4cb2835d02b

32 - 09fc12cfb0a81a38513dbd5edff19e52

32 - 35564354793555a3ae1382f647044445

Test : b96833277faf31a5915c769f44634506f89f6dd8cd5aee79de3b2c0c27cafe2ec9f629472c862c1e7542f4cb2835d02b09fc12cfb0a81a38513dbd5edff19e5235564354793555a3ae1382f647044445
```

Does anyone see the problem? I wish to use these hashes to compare them to others hashes.

Comment: You know, if you fire up your debugger, you can single step this code and see *exactly* where things are going wrong. If you don't know how to use your debugger, now is the perfect time to learn.

Comment: While `"%2.2x"` is fine, it is generally written as `"%02x"`.

Answer (score 1):

You should increase `unsigned char tmp[2]` to `unsigned char tmp[3]` and `unsigned char hash[8][32]` to `unsigned char hash[8][33];`

One problem is  `sprintf(tmp,"%2.2x",hashResults[k][i])`, because it writes two characters + '\0' which takes three elements in the array `tmp`.

But the biggest problem is `strcat(hash[k],tmp);`.
At the end of every inner for loop you have written in the hash[k] arrays 33 characters(32 chars + '\0'). What happens is when you populate one of the `hash[k]` arrays in the inner for loop you also write `\0'` to the first element in the next array, that's why `printf("%d \n%s\n", strlen(hash[k]), hash[k]);` prints correct results. That misleads you to believing you have null terminated the `hash[k]` arrays. Now when you enter the next inner for loop you override the null you have written to this array the previous time you exited the inner for loop, no longer terminating the previous array.

So you null terminate your `hash[k]` array by writing zero to the first element of the `hash[k+1]` array on the exit of the inner for loop. Then you override this null value every time you enter the inner for loop.

In the end you have no terminating nulls in your arrays and only the final null on the last array is there.

I wonder how do you even get this to work every time, because you write the terminating null beyond the array size which leads to undefined behavior.

Making `tmp[3]` and `hash[8][33]` should fix your problem.

In order for the strcat() function to work properly you have to have at least one null in the array you are concatenating to, because otherwise it wouldn't know where to concatenate to. You have to add hash[k][0] = 0; before entering every inner loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k)
{
    hash[k][0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(tmp,"%2.2x",hashResults[k][i]);
        strcat(hash[k],tmp);
    }
    printf("%d \n%s\n", strlen(hash[k]), hash[k]);
}
```

Comment: Your answer didn't fix the problem, with tmp[3] and hash[8][33] my strlen(hash[i]) takes respectively 38, 37, 36, ..., and 32 for the last hash. And values are not correct, : 
38 - @`By27b9a0940dc0645d477f19f6067b1c584

37 - 1c58414da5c01667c9b18d40134c5413b5305

36 -  53054a18e332afba75b9734e875323f452f8

35 - 2f8b96833277faf31a5915c769f44634506

Do you have another suggestion ? :D

Comment: In order for the `strcat()` function to work properly you have to have at least one null in the array you are concatenating to, because otherwise it wouldn't know where to concatenate to. You have to add `hash[k][0] = 0;` before entering every inner loop.